# Are CDNs that don't cache useful?

Tags: caching, cdn

Is there any benefit to (HTTP-) serving a non-cacheable resource over a CDN?

(my use case: I'm serving a static Single Page App and I'd like to improve its load time, but I don't want `index.html` to get cached, because I want every new release to be reflected immediately. Specifically, this static site is hosted on AWS S3, and the CDN is AWS CloudFront.)

I assume that most of the performance benefits of CDNs are achieved through caching, but I could imagine other benefits due to, say, priviledged network infrastructure. As I don't know the first thing about networks, this may sound like a silly question.

Comment: A CDN that doesn't cache will be useful to those who lived far-far away from your server, but near to the CDN , the latency will be better even though the content isn't being cached so, yeah... CDNs that don't cache **ARE useful**?

Comment: @FarizLuqman why the question mark?

Comment: whoops. my mistake. this is why I hope comments can be edited **always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be useful by moving the content closer to the user. Most CDN's will serve your static file from a geographical location as close to the user as possible, typically providing better latency.

Of course, you need to have users across the globe for this to make sense to you.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "useful by moving the content closer to the user", you mean moving it *faster* from you origin server than through the user's personal connection, correct?

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck, in the non-caching case, yes.